# Mule: How to use until successfull processor for service calls

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

Please help me on this logic. I have to call the service and get the response back.If the service is down or something have to retry 3 times  and once exhausted need to log in DLQ.I'm using **until successful** processor.For success scenario i'm getting only **null payload** in logger.But i tried keeping the HTTP outbound end point without until successfull able to get the response from the service. Please find my xml config.

```
              <flow name="Flow" doc:name="eFlow" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
                     <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="InputQ" tracking:enable-default-events="true" connector ref="WMQ_Connector" doc:name="connector">
                 <wmq:transaction action="NONE"/>
              </wmq:inbound-endpoint>
                  <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
                     <set-session-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]"       doc:name="Store_Payload"/>
                <choice tracking:enable-default-events="true" doc:name="Choice">
              <when expression="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])') == 'Master']">
                         <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Master_grf" doc:name="Master"/>
                    </when>
             <when expression="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])') == 'Request']">
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Request_grf" doc:name="Bulk"/>
             </when>
                    <otherwise>
            <scripting:component doc:name="Throw_Exception">
              <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new IllegalArgumentException  ('requests invalid') ]]>
           </otherwise>
                    </choice>
               <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
               <flow-ref name="Invoke_Service" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
              </flow>


                <flow name="Invoke_Service" doc:name="Invoke_Service" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
     <cxf:jaxws-client  enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP" operation="Request" serviceClass="com.valid.ICase"/>
       <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="3" secondsBetweenRetries="2"  deadLetterQueue-ref="VM" doc:name="UntilSuccessful_SymboticService">
       <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"    method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://localhost:1112/symbotic"/>
          </until-successful>  
       <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger message="**********success***Payload: #[payload]*****" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

But incase of failure scenario until success retry 3 times ( works fine). I have tried request reply processor inside until also transactional processor. It is not working. Using Mule version 3.4.kindly suggest me.

Retried the same  with request -reply processor as per the suggestion

```
      <flow name="Flow" doc:name="eFlow" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
             <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="InputQ" tracking:enable-default-events="true" connector-           ref="WMQ_Connector" doc:name="connector">
    <wmq:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </wmq:inbound-endpoint>
           <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
        <set-session-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Store_Payload"/>
         <choice tracking:enable-default-events="true" doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])') == 'Master']">
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Master_grf" doc:name="Master"/>
    </when>
    <when expression="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])') == 'Request']">
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Request_grf" doc:name="Bulk"/>
    </when>
 <otherwise>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Throw_Exception">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new IllegalArgumentException('requests           other then Master andRequest') ]]>
    </otherwise>
 </choice>
  <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
  <request-reply timeout="10000">
 <vm:outbound-endpoint path="request"/>      
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="reply"/>
   </request-reply> 
  <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
<logger message="**********success***Payload: #[payload]*****" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>     
  </flow>

  <flow name="Invoke_Service" doc:name="Invoke_Service" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
<vm:inbound-endpoint path="request" doc:name="VM"/>
 <cxf:jaxws-client  enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP" operation="Request"    serviceClass="com.valid.ICase"/>
   <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="3" secondsBetweenRetries="2"  deadLetterQueue-ref="VM" doc:name="UntilSuccessful_Service">
   <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"    method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://localhost:1112/symbotic"/>
   </until-successful> 
   </flow>
```

Even then getting the **null payload**. Kindly suggest is this is the way your were directing me. Please correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`until-successful` is an `asynchronous` processor. It does not return response from service call.

`Success` or `failure` are defined as:

1. If the child message processor throws an exception, this is a failure.
2. If the child message processor does not return a message (e.g. is a one-way endpoint), this is a success.
3. If a 'failure expression' (see below) has been configured, the return message is evaluated against this expression to determine failure or not.
4. Otherwise:

   1. If the child message processor returns a message that contains an exception payload, this is a failure.
   2. If the child message processor returns a message that does not contain an exception payload, this is a success.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-UntilSuccessful

Comment: Is there any other way, we can use until successful for sync process.Or kindly suggest how can we handle retry process with service call together.I have read some blogs but didn't get it clearly.

Comment: `async <request-reply>` is way for handling synchronous response. For retrying process, after web service call, check the response using `choice` router and push failed responses to `JMS` queue and have a `quartz` component on that JMS queue and it will try to deliver request

Comment: Using `<request-reply>` is the right approach, you can simply use `VM` queues and no need for `quartz`.

Comment: @DavidDossot without using `quartz`, then mule will keep on retrying continuously failed messages.. right? Yes, we can certainly do that, `quartz` provides a way to configure retry policy (helpful in case when end server is down)

Comment: I don't get it. You put the `until-successful` in a flow and call it via an `VM` queue from the main flow through a `request-reply`. Inside the `until-successful`, after the HTTP call, you send the response back to the response `VM` queue defined in `request-reply`. No need for `quartz`.

Comment: Thank you @Learner for your suggestions and explanation.

Comment: Thank you @DavidDossot: I have tried the way but still facing the same error.I have added the xml config.Kindly have a glance.

Comment: Add `<vm:outbound-endpoint path="reply"/>` after the `http:outbound-endpoint` in the `until-successful`.

Comment: In until successful message processor , wrapping HTTP along with other message processors inside "processor-chain" works fine. We can able to get sync response in-case of success also can do retries if message fails.

Comment: @DavidDossot Until successful allows one child inside. So i'm unable to keep `VM:Outbound` after HTTP. But i placed outside the until-successful. Null payload only. Also i tried keeping request reply processor( with HTTP and VM:outbound) inside until. But again null payload only.

Comment: Use a `processor-chain` to wrap multiple elements into one.